# Oledb or ODBC Create workbook or Worksheet without Office installed

Tags: vb.net, excel, odbc, oledb, oledbconnection

I have a 2008R2 server with SQL and IIS; no MS-Office suit installed, however I need to send dynamically created Excel replies based on user requests.

The "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable" is installed, as per the specs, the Excel driver (among others) should be in place.

Trying to create a new database with the following connection string:

```
    Using ExcelConnection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(
          "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
          "Data Source=" + Name + ";" +
          "Mode=ReadWrite;" +
          "ReadOnly=false;" +
          "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
        ExcelConnection.Open()
    ....
    end Using
```

The error

```
  [OleDbException (0x80004005): Could not find installable ISAM.]
  System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection) +318
  System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject) +88
  System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +24
  ....
```

Removing `Mode=ReadWrite;ReadOnly=false;`  fail with a different error:

```
OleDbException (0x80004005): Cannot update.  Database or object is read-only.]
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection) +318
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions .....
```

The output directory security allows create without restrictions.

If I have a 'template', I can copy it and work with it. So: creation is not allowed but read/write is.

Please no advise to use CSV, third party software or anything other than a well formed Excel Workbook with one or more Worksheets.

Sorry my language: I'm fluent in C#, but prefer to write in VB...

Comment: Try with  "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;"""

Comment: @steve not enough... keep failing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a blank new Excel file, you need to specify "Excel 12.0 XML" in your extended properties, E.g.

```
Using ExcelConnection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(
      "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
      "Data Source=" + Name + ";" +
      "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 XML;")
    ExcelConnection.Open()
End Using
```

Also, please note the Excel file will not be complete until you add at least one sheet...

```
Using ExcelCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("Create Table [Sheet1] (Column1 Int)", ExcelConnection)
    ExcelCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

However reading an existing one, possibly after you've copied a template from elsewhere will require you to use different extended properties...

```
Using ExcelConnection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(
      "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
      "Data Source=" + Name + ";" +
      "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1"""
    ExcelConnection.Open()
End Using
```

You may have headers in which case specify HDR=Yes. Personally I prefer not to.